# Not all BTRFS devices are found during boot

Tags: boot, btrfs

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 with a view to moving Ubuntu 22.04, because I've fallen behind.

My root filesystem is BTRFS and is spread across three devices, some of which are partitioned.

One such "device" is `/dev/sdb10`, which contains part of the root filesystem.

At first, I had no problems at all.

Then, during some `dist-upgrade` in 18.04 the boot would fail. I added `root=/dev/sdb10` to the kernel command line and this started working. The filesystem itself had no errors, so something changed, as usual.

I have since run a `do-release-upgrade` which completed successfully.

On reboot the system drops to `(initramfs)` after reporting:

`Alert!! /dev/sdb10 does not exist !!` (or words to that effect).

`ls /dev/sdb*` shows that it does, indeed exist.

`dmesg` shows that the BTRFS scan does indeed fail to find this partition during boot, and yet it does exist.

Booting GParted Live 1.4.0-5 sees a similar issue: I cannot mount this filesystem and GParted gives misleading information about the partition. (Though I can mount it degraded with the device missing, which isn't much use).

However, running `btrfs dev scan` finds `/dev/sdb10` and I can mount the filesystem without issue.

So I am at a loss. I have tried searching for a way to force the "scan" to find this partition, including adding all the devices to `fstab` but it makes no difference.

I can't even work out what is doing this "scan". Is it part of the initramfs? udev? Some script? I don't know where to start!

The BTRFS driver for Windows 10 (which is what I'm using to write this) find the whole filesystem without any problems, and always has.

I tried adding some udev debug flags to the kernel commandline but there's too much for the scrollback buffer, and none of it is saved anywhere (it doesn't appear in `dmesg`).

Help!

Answer (score 0):

After deep-diving into the various scripts I finally found a solution to get my system back into a working state.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

modprobe btrfs
/bin/btrfs device scan

# Required because `btrfs device scan` doesn't appear
# to scan past 9 partitions!
/bin/btrfs device ready /dev/sdb10
```

I consider this a workaround and suspect that there is a bug (or bad design choice) waiting to be reported.

Ideally I would first pull in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount` but I couldn't figure out how to do that without messing with the scripts in the `hooks` directory. It may be something I end up doing in the future.

This also means I could remove `root=/dev/sdb10` from my kernel command line.

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-progs/+bug/1989677

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue, and have seen that the nvme numbering is not stable (I am in raid 1 between two BTRFS for linux and the third is a windows). Sometime the windows and mirror btrfs change system nvme number...

I've tried your idea but it does not help at boot recovery either.
Due to instability, I've added the by-uuid with no more success

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).